# The differences between “je”, “jeder”, “jegliche”, and “jeweilig”

Tags: adjective, pronoun

I struggle a lot when I encounter one of the words in the “je-group”, that is, “je”, “jeder”, “jegliche”, and “jeweilig”, to see their differences in meaning.

To me, they always translate to “all”/“every” or “each” in English. 
I would like to know if there are nuanced differences in their usage, meaning, and connotation.

Comment: Try to think German. Do not translate it into a foreign language (like English) and analyze it in this foreign language. This will not work.

Comment: That's definitely what one should do; but at the early stages, one cannot do that without recourse to a language one knows.

Comment: I could understand that "jeder" and"jegliche" can be translated as "every/all". But "je" and "jeweilig"? They have different meanings.

Comment: What did the dictionary say? With 4 words, you can build 6 differences, that's too broad, imho.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Maybe these examples can help you:

- **je (1)** (Adverb)
  Only in questions: *at any time?*

  > Gibt es Bigfoot wirklich? Hat man ihn wirklich **je** gesehen?
  >   Is Bigfoot real? Has anybody **ever** seen him?
  >
  > Werden Menschen **je** einen Fuß auf den Mars setzen?
  >   Will people **ever** set foot on Mars?
- **je (2)** (Präposition)
  *per*

  > Ich rechne mit drei Flaschen Bier **je** Besucher.
  >   I reckon three bottles of beer **per** visitor.
  >
  > Acht Tonnen auf nur vier Rädern sind zwei Tonnen **je** Rad.
  >   Eight tonnes on only four wheels makes two tonnes **per** wheel.
- **je (3)** (Interjektion)
  etymologically a contraction of »Jesus«

  > **Herr je**! Was hast du gemacht?
  >   **Oh Lord**! What did you do?
  >
  > **Oh je**! Nun ist es zerbrochen!
  >   **Oh man**! Now it is broken!
- **je nach, je nachdem**  (Adverb + »nach, nachdem«) (nach = Präposition; nachdem = Subjunktion)
  *depending on*

  > **Je nach** Ergebnis des Test kann ich heimgehen, oder muss noch bleiben.
  >   **Depending on** the results of the test I can go home or must stay.
  >
  > Wir werden auf Platz 1 oder 2 landen, **je nachdem** wie das heutige Spiel ausgeht.
  >   We will reach rank 1 or 2, **depending on** how today's game ends.
- **je ... desto** (Adverb) (desto = Konjunktion)
  *the ... the*

  > **Je** mehr ich esse, **desto** dicker werde ich.
  >   **The** more I eat, **the** fatter I grow.
  >
  > **Je** höher wir klettern, **desto** schwerer kann ich atmen.
  >   **The** higher we climb, **the** harder I find it to breath.
- **jeder, jede, jedes** (Indefinitpronomen)
  A single person or thing as part of a group. Either together with all other members of the group, or on its own.

  > Das weiß doch **jeder.**
  >   **Everybody** knows that. (literally: **Every** knows that.)
  >
  > Das weiß doch **jeder** Mensch.
  >   **Everybody** knows that. (literally: **Every** human knows that.)
  >
  > **Jeder** Besucher braucht eine Eintrittskarte.
  >   **Every** visitor needs a ticket.
  >
  > **Jeder** Besucher bekommt einen Hut.
  >   **Each** visitor gets a hat.
- **jeglicher, jegliche, jegliches** (Indefinitpronomen)
  Synonym of *jeder, jede, jedes*, but used for abstract entities (not for persons).

  > Ich habe **jegliches** Interesse an diesem Spiel verloren.
  >   I've lost **all** interest in this game.
  >
  > **Jegliche** Einmischung wird bestraft.
  >   **Any** interference will be punished.
  >
  > Deine Argumentation entbehrt **jeglicher** Grundlage!
  >   Your argument is without foundation! (literally: Your argument lacks **any** foundation!)
- **jeweilig** (Adjektiv)
  *respective*

  > Jeder der drei Männer ging zu seinem **jeweiligen** Auto.
  >   Each of the three men went to his **respective** car.
  >
  > Die Könige herrschten über ihr **jeweiliges** Reich.
  >   The kings ruled over their **respective** realms.

Comment: "je(1)" is equivalent to "jemals"

Comment: Could you tell me the proper meaning of “jeweiligen” in the following:
“Politik ist insoweit ein Prozeß der Selbstauslegung des Menschen in jeweiligen gesellschaftlichen Verhältnissen.”

Comment: @PhilosophiaeNaturalis: [Google translator](https://translate.google.com) says: »Politics is to this extent a process of the self-interpretation of man in the respective social conditions.«